# schedule running a bash shell script in windows (question2)

Tags: windows, bash, shell, cygwin

Apreciate any help and excuse me if my terminology is incorrect.

building on from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517909/schedule-running-a-bash-shell-script-in-windows):

i am trying to run a .sh file, and I do this by using the answer in the question above, which is basically 

1 - associating my file **filename.sh** with the **filename.bat**

 **filename.bat** looks like this:

```
@echo off

c:
chdir c:\cygwin\bin

bash --login %*
```

This generally works for most of my *.sh files with an example being this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Configure bash so the script will exit if a command fails.
set -e 

#this is the DIR i want to copy to 
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
#this is the DIR i want to copy from
DIR2=/cygdrive/v/where/file/is

#cd to the dir where I want to copy the files to:
cd "$DIR"

#cp files and subdirectories of interest
#include the subdirs 
cp -r "$DIR2"/* .

# This will unzip all .zip files in all subdirectories under this one.
# -o is required to overwrite everything that is in there
find -iname '*.zip' -execdir unzip -o {} \;

# this will delete row 1-6 and the last row of all the csv files 
find ./ -iname '*.csv' -exec sed -i '1,6d;$ d' '{}' ';'
```

So the above works when I double click on it.

Some instances I have noted that do not work when I double click on them, is when the script contains something like below:

1->

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"/PointB
    echo $DIR > test.txt #the text.txt file will not be created
```

2->

```
#this renames files in a directory, see [here][2]
for fname in Combined*.csv ; do mv "$fname" "$(echo "$fname" | sed -r 's/[0-9]{14}//')" ; done
```

But 1 & 2 above will work if i run them from cygwin with the command `./filename.sh`

What I am wondering is why is 1 and 2 above not work for me, by double clicking on them, when they do work by invoking the command `./filename.sh`?

Note: I am running cygwin on windows XP

**EDIT: This is what I get when I say it does not work by double clicking it** in that the cmd window opens up and displays this.

[image: This is what I get when I say it does not work by double clicking it]
FormatCSVFiles.sh is the file I am double clicking on.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Is there an error message?

Comment: @tripleee good point, I have updated my question, let me know if there is anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction: this actually works. I was not changing directory before giving the echo command. So a silly mistake by me . tks.