# How can I make sure I am running the latest version of the code from GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh, version-control, remote-server

I am fairly new to git and am a bit confused as to how to set up my workflow to work in the most convenient way possible.

I am working on my laptop (running OSX) and our much beefier server (running CentOS) through ssh, where I try and run time consuming tests for my Python code. Doing this for a few months I quickly realised that I was having parallel but separate lines of development since the folder structure is quite different.

I have thus taken the time to set up a github repo and cloned it into my laptop. Then I diffed the python files pairwise (server version vs laptop version) manually merged the differences and pushed the files up to Github. Lastly I cloned the repo on the server. Now I have the same version on all three places which is great.

In the future, I would like to avoid the divergence between the different platforms. Ideally I would like to **automatically** sync the local repo with Github every time I log in (should in theory be possible to do in .bashrc?), and log out, of the server. Essentially I am trying to avoid the chance that I forget manually syncing between the different machines.

How can I achieve this? Are there any potential pitfalls to this strategy?

Comment: That's called continuous deployment. Here's [an article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-with-jenkins--cms-21511) on how to accomplish that with a tool called Jenkins (one popular option amongst web devs and GitHub users... but there are many, many others).

Comment: To those who voted close on basis of broadness, what specific detail was missing? I am happy to provide more details but I feel the question is specific enough to warrant useful answers. It might be simple ones for many here, but last I checked SO was where people asked questions to learn about things they don't know/understand well. Also, the fact that there may be many possible solutions to a problem doesn't mean that the question is not answerable.

Comment: [From the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): "***avoid asking subjective questions where …** every answer is equally valid*" I think it's a perfectly fine question to ask, just not on SO. There are whole books written on CI & CD. There's no one right answer here... it all depends on your experience, budget, security concerns, workflow, preferences, etc. It's a very broad subject. This is very close to a "which tool should I use"-type question, but you avoided asking that directly, so I voted to close as "too broad". (Did not -1, though)

Comment: Here's a list of some of the books that have been written on this subject: https://ssearch.oreilly.com/?q=continuous+delivery

Answer (score 0):

For git itself, there is no such hooks or settings to automatically sync local repo with remote repo.

The work around is **schedule to run a script to sync local repo with remote repo**.

The sync script example (sync `master` branch) as below:

```
#!/bin/sh

git fetch
flag=0
ahead=$(git log origin/master..master --oneline)
if [[ -z "${ahead// }" ]]; then
  echo "Local repo has no commits un-pushed"
else
  {
    flag=1
    echo "local master branch is ahead of origin/master $flag"
  }
fi
behind=$(git log master..origin/master --oneline)
if [[ -z "${behind// }" ]]; then
  {
    if [ $flag == 0 ]; then
      echo "already sync"
    else
      git push
    fi
  }
else
  {
    if [ $flag == 0 ]; then
      git pull origin master
    else
    {
      git pull origin master --rebase
      git push
    }
    fi
  }
fi
echo "Now the local repo is aync eith remote repo"
```

To schedule runs the scripts, you can refer:

[schedule running a bash shell script in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517909/schedule-running-a-bash-shell-script-in-windows)

[Running .sh every 5 minutes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738180/running-sh-every-5-minutes)

You can also related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399566/automatic-commit-and-push-to-github-from-android-studio/45406306#45406306).