# Sync one local repo with the remote git repository

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git repository with many people contributing to it. So every user having their own repository checked out locally in their workspace. I would like to maintain one more local repo as a centralized place to look for the latest code. So I would like to have an exact replica of the remote repository. By which, I mean my centralized repo should be in sync with the remote repository all the time (24/7). So I am looking for something like if someone pushes a new commit to the remote repo, my centralized repo should checkout(git pull) latest code to have the updated code all the time. Please tell me how could I achieve this

Comment: You have a number of options. All require work on your part; all have flaws. There's a fundamental problem and you must decide what to do about it: what happens if the network is partitioned, or some machine goes down, so that your local-but-centralized repo cannot talk with the remote repo for, say, one hour, or one day, or one week, or one year? Decide that; the rest follows from there.

Comment: Assuming the network is intact all the time, can we achieve this?

Comment: Sure: write software that, upon receiving an update at your master remote, signals to the slave-local that the slave-local should update itself. That can be as simple as running `git push` from the master to the slave-local (this assumes the slave-local repository is bare or otherwise allows pushes from the master). The software you write can be as simple as a one-line post-receive hook that runs `git push --mirror <url-or-name>`.

Answer (score 0):

For the local git repo (even you treat it as a centralized place), it can not sync  with remote git repo automatically.

There are two ways to sync local repo if there has new changes in remote repo:

#### Option 1: schedule to run a script to execute git pull for time to time

The script can be:

```
#!/bin/sh

git fetch -p
for bran in $(git branch -r)
do
{
  if [[ $bran == *"origin/HEAD -> origin/"* ]]; then
  echo "this is not a branch"
  else
  {
    localb=$(echo $bran | cut -d'/' -f 2)
    echo "This is $localb branch"
    git checkout $localb
    git pull origin $localb
  }
  fi
}
done
```

Schedule to run the script, you can refer:

[schedule running a bash shell script in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517909/schedule-running-a-bash-shell-script-in-windows)

[Running .sh every 5 minutes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738180/running-sh-every-5-minutes)

#### Option 2: use post-receive hook to update the local repo

Use post-receive hook so that when changes are pushed to remote repo, then execute the script automatically.

Comment: I could write a cron job as you suggested. But I don't want to run the script unnecessarily even when there is no commit (which is of no use). I am looking for something like interrupt based mechanism so that only when there is a new commit/change merged to remote, then we will run this script (something like git hooks). But I couldn't find any such.

Comment: It works in shell script perfectly, please make sure the directory is a git repo where the scripts executed. And unless the remote repo server-side hooks are available, you can use post-receive hook update the local repo after changes pushed to remote repo.

Comment: So you mean to say remote repo should be having some hooks to notify the local-centralized repo about a new merge/commit?

Comment: Yes, but if your remote repo hosted in third part, such as github, the server-side hooks are not available.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. So, What if i try to have my remote repo hosted in some machine which i have access, then can we do this? Any such example hooks available? (I am trying to reduce the load on my machine by avoiding running the script every 5 minutes)

Comment: If the server-side hooks can be available for your, it's not necessary to schedule to run hook (such as every 5 mins), because (such as post-receive) hook will be automatically triggered after changes pushed to remote repo.

Comment: Have you sync local repo with remote repo by local scripts or post-receive hook successful now?

Comment: I didn't check that yet. I need to check the remote repo(access permissions) and post-receive hook for implementation.

Comment: Ok, feel free to let me know if you have problem setting the post-receive hook.

Comment: Sure, will check and let you know if I face any issues